# Substring from path string

Tags: c#, substring

In strings like this (I get strings from `Directory.GetFiles()`)

```
string temp = "\\folder_name\\file_name.filetype.[somename@somedomain].wallet"
```

What is the best way to substring: `file_name.filetype`

I could do something like this:

```
const string source = ".[somename@somedomain].wallet";
temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf(source, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

... but problem is that "mail" in string ".[xxxx@xxxx].wallet" is changing, in my words my string source should be something like this:

```
const string source = ".[*].wallet"; //so all strings that are in .[all_strings].wallet
```

Is there an easy way to do something like this (with asterisk "*"), or I will have to substring piece by piece and concatenate this new string?

Comment: You need to store this in HTML so you can use a regex to parse it.

Comment: You can do the way you're thinking, use a regex

Comment: Ed, HTML? Why?!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Regex, hmm it could help, tnx, let me search more

Comment: You have a filename. The right way to parse file names is with the `Path` class. In your case, you can use `GetFileName()` to get the full file name everything after the last directory separator), and then iteratively use `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` to work your way back to the last two "non-extension" components of the file name. See marked duplicate for additional details.

Comment: the first group of this regex should be what you are looking for `^.*\\\\(.*)\\.\\[.*\\]\\.wallet$`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti [No reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/424129).

Comment: None of the duplicates linked above addresses the problem directly. The problem is not only to remove the prefix, but also to match and discard the suffix. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Ed ahahahahahahah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a regex that requires a backslash before the substring of interest, and a text in square brackets followed by `.wallet` at the end.

Here is how you can do with in C# regex APIs:

```
string temp = @"\folder_name\file_name.filetype.[somename@somedomain].wallet";
var m = Regex.Match(temp, @"(?<=\\)[^.]*\.[^.]*(?=\.\[[^\]]*\].wallet)");
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("<no match>");
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nsmCcw)

`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` constructs are zero-length look-ahead and look-behind. They are not included in the `m.Value`.

Comment: Respect, exactly what I am searcing for.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the 2nd index of `.` and take everything before that point.

```
string temp = "\\folder_name\\file_name.filetype.[somename@somedomain].wallet";

var filename = Path.GetFileName(temp);
var lastIndex = filename.IndexOf('.', filename.IndexOf('.') + 1);
var fileYouAreLookingFor = filename.Substring(0, lastIndex);
```

[Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bQ6vA4)

Comment: I don't mind being corrected or downvoted but I do appreciate a comment on why the answer was downvoted.

Comment: I don't know who or why you have been downvoted, or how is this question duplicated, I can find from Peter Duhino questions where is duplicated, but from your answer I can find right solution, because my strings are exactly finished with ".[XXXX@XXX.com].wallet so correct, for me this is an answer of my problem

Comment: @DaniKR - also feel free to up-vote any answers that you feel helped you get to the correct solution.

Comment: thanks for answer, my upwote, but answer from dasblinkenlight is what is I was looking for, but still thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an regex to achieve this. The first group of the following one should be what you are looking for.

```
string temp = "\\folder_name\\file_name.filetype.[somename@somedomain].wallet";

var filenameRegex = new Regex("^.*\\\\(.*)\\.\\[.*\\]\\.wallet$");
var match = filenameRegex.Match(temp);

var result = match.Groups[1];
```